# How to prevent any changes in code and be able at same time to look at it? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Is there, by chance, any way to prevent from changing code and simultaneously be able to look at it?
The purpose is introductory, so that user could look at code without ability to do any changes.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Just make the workbook read only.

Comment: Perhaps just a copy of the workbook that is wide open for them to look at the code (where they use the production copy that is locked down, but can still see what's humming behind the scenes)?

Comment: You can also put the code in a protected workbook and keep the data in an open one.

Comment: Are users supposed to run the code too? if yes, then give them a copy and it does not matter what they do with it, because you won't use it for the production, if no, then just copy the code in a notepad+, pdf or sth like that and let them see it

Comment: I agree with Comintern's suggestion. `File > Save as > General option > Leave password to open as blank, but enter password to modify > Enter filename and save`. Now the user shouldn't be able to save any changes to the workbook itself, unless they provided the corect password at the time of opening  the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tricky one. You can add the following **three** subscripts and it will make the file Read Only and also stop anyone from saving the workbook unless they use the SaveForReal Subscript/Macro.

Inside the ThisWorkbook VBA Object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Inside a Module Object:

```
Private Sub SaveForReal()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

To save the workbook, you need to open the VBA editor and Run the SaveForReal Subscript, otherwise the Save Button and Save As button does nothing.

Edit: Added On Open Read Only Change.